# Make combinations in R

Tags: r

I want to make combinations of names from the same column (here, changing names to numbers for easier visual)

Given the following data:

```
Col1
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How do I generate the following:

```
Col1   Col2
1      2
1      3
2      3
1      4
2      4
3      4
1      5
2      5
3      5
4      5
1      6
2      6
3      6
4      6
5      6

test <- combn(data$`row ID`,2)
test <- t(test)
```

I get:

```
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   6
2   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
3   4
3   5
3   6
4   5
4   6
5   6
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: just do `test[order(test[,2]),]`

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 1:NROW(d)
data.frame(Col1 = d$Col1[sequence(head(i, -1))],
           Col2 = d$Col1[rep(i[-1], head(i, -1))])
#   Col1 Col2
#1     1    2
#2     1    3
#3     2    3
#4     1    4
#5     2    4
#6     3    4
#7     1    5
#8     2    5
#9     3    5
#10    4    5
#11    1    6
#12    2    6
#13    3    6
#14    4    6
#15    5    6
```

**DATA**

```
d = data.frame(Col1 = 1:6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `order` your text matrix using the second column

```
setNames(data.frame(test[order(test[,2]),]),paste0("col",1:2))
   col1 col2
1     1    2
2     1    3
3     2    3
4     1    4
5     2    4
6     3    4
7     1    5
8     2    5
9     3    5
10    4    5
11    1    6
12    2    6
13    3    6
14    4    6
15    5    6
```

Comment: @d.b we need to order by the value. I do not understand what ordering by ndex means. It is already ordered by index. So we change it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way in base R using `expand.grid` and `subset` -

```
# domains of values for col1 and col2 are certainly known beforehand
# so can be directly input/generated to be used in expand.grid()
subset(expand.grid(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 2:6), col1 < col2)

   col1 col2
1     1    2
6     1    3
7     2    3
11    1    4
12    2    4
13    3    4
16    1    5
17    2    5
18    3    5
19    4    5
21    1    6
22    2    6
23    3    6
24    4    6
25    5    6
```

Another approach using `lapply` -

```
col1 = 1:5
col2 = 2:6

do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(col1, function(x) cbind(col1 = x, col2 = col2[x < col2]))
)

      col1 col2
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    1    6
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    2    4
 [8,]    2    5
 [9,]    2    6
[10,]    3    4
[11,]    3    5
[12,]    3    6
[13,]    4    5
[14,]    4    6
[15,]    5    6
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want is to `cbind` growing sequences based on `x`-value of `Col1` with `x + 1` `rep`eated `x` times. You could write a function `f` that does exactly this,

```
f <- function(x) cbind(seq(x), rep(x + 1, x))
```

`Map`ply it on `Col1`, and `rbind` the result.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(f, d$Col1[-length(d$Col1)]))
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    1    2
#  [2,]    1    3
#  [3,]    2    3
#  [4,]    1    4
#  [5,]    2    4
#  [6,]    3    4
#  [7,]    1    5
#  [8,]    2    5
#  [9,]    3    5
# [10,]    4    5
# [11,]    1    6
# [12,]    2    6
# [13,]    3    6
# [14,]    4    6
# [15,]    5    6
```

#### Data

```
d <- data.frame(Col1=1:6)
```